# Content table framed by red rectangle

Tags: table-of-contents

I've made a basic latex document and the different sections of my content page are framed by a red rectangle:
[image: probleme]
I have tried on different reader and it's still the same result.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
asd
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Test}
\section{section2} % (fold)
\label{sec:section2}
\end{document}
```

Thx for the help

Comment: That's the standard behavior of `hyperref`, see the link of my previous comment to know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you haven't red boxed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
asd
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Test}
\section{section2} % (fold)
\label{sec:section2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If ok, or vote my question or check my answer :-). Hi, and good work.